# How to fix "Error converting column: 0 TO TIMESTAMP"?

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, impala

I have data in text files stored on HDFS with following directory structure :

```
/exported/year/07/month/hour/SEARCHES/
/exported/2014/07/01/00/SEARCHES/part-m-00000
                                 part-m-00001
/exported/2014/07/01/02/SEARCHES/part-m-00000
                                 part-m-00001
                                 part-m-00003
.
.
.
.
/exported/2014/08/01/09/SEARCHES/part-m-00005
```

So I have created an external table in impala with following query :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE search
  (time_stamp TIMESTAMP, url STRING, domain STRING, ............ keyword STRING)
PARTITIONED BY (year INT, month INT, day INT, hour INT)
  row format delimited fields terminated by '\t';
```

And loaded data into it with :

```
ALTER TABLE search_mmx ADD PARTITION (year=2014, month=08, day=${d}, hour=${h})
LOCATION '/exported/2014/08/${d}/${h}/SEARCHES/';
```

for all available days & hours. It was loaded successfully, I verified this by counting # of rows.

But when i try to `select * from search limit 10;` it gave error "Error converting column: 0 TO TIMESTAMP (Data is: 1406965816)"

Original value of time_stamp is Unix timestamp format. How do I convert it from unix timestamp to Impala TIMESTAMP datatype ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for the TIMESTAMP data type](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_timestamp.html):

> You can [cast](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_conversion_functions.html) an integer or floating-point value N to TIMESTAMP, producing a value that is N seconds past the start of the epoch date (January 1, 1970).

Also:

> Note: In Impala 1.3 and higher, the FROM_UNIXTIME() and UNIX_TIMESTAMP() [functions](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_datetime_functions.html) allow a wider range of format strings, with more flexibility in element order, repetition of letter placeholders, and separator characters. See Date and Time Functions for details.

Comment: can we do something like this which I have used in Vetica

COPY public.test (unix_timestamp FILLER VARCHAR(15), datetime AS TO_TIMESTAMP(unix_timestamp)) SOURCE Hdfs(.....) filter BZip() DELIMITER E'\t';
to convert unix_timestamp into TIMESTAMP on the fly while loading into table ?

Comment: If you change your CREATE statement to say "time_stamp STRING" you should be able to CAST(time_stamp AS TIMESTAMP when you SELECT from the search table. You could then, for example, use an ALTER TABLE, a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT, or CREATE VIEW to alter search or create another table/view where the time_stamp column is CAST to TIMESTAMP rather than STRING.

Comment: Cant it be done on the fly when data is ingested into table, because we will be continuously adding data to this table and removing data older than 90 days. so something we want to do at the beginning rathere than doing at query time to avoid delay in query processing.